# Ocultar URL de Descarga Externa con Nombre de (Sub)dominio Externo (WP)

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, wordpress-theme, headers

Tengo un pequeño script que permite descargar archivos desde un servidor externo, y refleja en la url de descarga como si el archivo se descargara desde la dirección url en la que está el archivo PHP que contiene el código de este script.

Este script lo encontré Googleando, es muy similar a lo que yo buscaba, pero no funcionaba y me tocó hacerle varias modificaciones para que volviera a andar a pesar de nunca haber trabajado con encabezados, probando y tratando de descifrar el funcionamiento lo logré.

**Explicación de Funcionamiento**

Este Script actualmente lo ejecuto ingresando la url directamente en el navegador así http://miwordpress.com/descargas.php entonces me da a elegir desde una lista, el archivo que necesito descargar, cabe mencionar que dichos archivos se encuentran alojados para este caso en: http://mirror.unimagdalena.edu.co/centos/7.7.1908/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1908.iso  y http://mirror.unimagdalena.edu.co/centos/7.7.1908/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-1908.iso , cuando hago click para descargar uno de ellos enseguida la descarga comienza pero reemplaza estas URL por un simple ID y el dominio desde el que se ejecuta el script en este caso las URL serian: http://miwordpress.com/descargas.php?0 y http://miwordpress.com/descargas.php?1 respectivamente.

**El Problema**

Bueno resulta que deseo que el script muestre una URL y dominio distinto al actual, es decir ya no quiero que muestre la fuente de descarga como http://miwordpress.com/descargas.php?0 sino otro dominio bajo mi poder (me imagino debe ser así) como digamos http://downmiwp.com/descargas.php?0. Por otro lado necesito que este mismo script se pueda ejecutar en las entradas de Blog (Single.php de WP), para cada entrada tendré URLS externas de archivos diferentes que le proporcionaré al script a través de una variable PHP.

Para comenzar lo que se me ocurrió como solución, fue intentar con un simple

`<?php echo file_get_contents('http://miwordpress.com/descargas.php'); ?>`

Y rogar para que funcione al momento de hacer click en el archivo a descargar, pero sencillamente no muestra nada. Lo de cambiar la URL por otro dominio si no tengo idea cómo hacerlo.

A continuación adjunto el código respectivo que tiene el script compuesto por un solo archivo llamado descargas.php.

Contenido achivo descargas.php

```
$files=array( 'CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1908.iso', 'CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-1908.iso');
$filenames=array( 'CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1908.iso', 'CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-1908.iso');
$url= "http://mirror.unimagdalena.edu.co/centos/7.7.1908/isos/x86_64/";

$PHP_SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
$HTTP_HOST = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $HTTP_REFERER = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

 } else {
    $HTTP_REFERER = '';

 }

$referer= preg_replace( '/\?./', '',$HTTP_REFERER);
$thisfile= "http://$HTTP_HOST$PHP_SELF"; 

function Getsize($url) {
$remoteFile = $url;
$curl = curl_init($remoteFile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
url_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($curl);
$fileSize = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
curl_close($curl);
return $fileSize;

}


if ($referer!=$thisfile) {
for ($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++) {
echo '<P><A HREF="'.$PHP_SELF.'?'.$i.'">'.$filenames[$i].'</A>'; }
} else {
$QUERY_STRING = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$i=$QUERY_STRING;
$total= "$url$files[$i]";
$size = Getsize("$total");

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$files[$i]);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.$size);
readfile($total);

}
```

**Algunos detalles (Para este ejemplo):**

1. Archivos Alojado en: http://mirror.unimagdalena.edu.co
2. WordPress Alojado en Dominio www.miwordpress.com.
3. Entrada de Blog de ejemplo ubicada en: www.miwordpress.com/entrada1

**En Conclusión Necesito:**

1. Integrar este script con las entradas de WP.
2. Poder usar otro dominio o subdominio distinto al donde se encuentra alojada mi instalación de WP (en este caso es el mismo donde se aloja el archivo descargas.php del script).

Comment: Si tu blog está en el dominio A, y el archivo en el dominio B, por qué quieres meter en el medio un dominio C? Por otro lado, si en tu blog enlazas directamente al archivo (e.g. http://miwordpress.com/descargas.php?0) la descarga debiera iniciar sin cambiar de URL

Comment: Me perdí entre tantas explicaciones. Quizá conviene que expliques el problema que tienes en un sólo párrafo. En casos como estos, explicando el problema ya tienes la solución. Se me ocurre por ejemplo, ¿por qué cuando se da clic en un enlace no lanzas la descarga directamente, por qué te lías con que si la URL tal o cual? Explica en un sólo párrafo el contexto y el problema y quizá podremos ayudarte mejor. Un ejemplo de explicación en un sólo párrafo: *Tengo los archivos en tal sitio, tienen que descargarse desde tal sitio, la descarga tiene que ser de este tipo.*

Comment: @amendiel Solo quiero que se publiquen los enlaces de descarga en la correspondiente entrada de blog del dominio miwordpress.com y al momento de descargar se descargue SUPUESTAMENTE desde otra dirección de dominio para este ejemplo ilustrativo será downmiwp.com. Lo de enlazar el archivo: primero seria antiestético, quiero que en la misma entrada de blog ya se generen los enlaces, segundo esos enlaces de descarga que se generan no son únicos, es decir si ingresara la dirección miwordpress.com/descargas.php?0 no conseguiría descargar nada directamente, solo me lleva al listado de archivos.

Comment: Quieres que en la entrada del blog se generen los enlaces sin escribirlos específicamente? Algo así como usando custom fields en cada post?

Comment: @amenadiel es preciso !! Uso un Custom Field.

Comment: Cuál es el sentido del $referer? la idea es no permitir que se descargue directo del post?

Comment: @amenadiel La idea del refer es brindar una identificación unica para cada archivo (el refer es solo el ID/Key del array) que esté enlazado para descarga dentro de la entrada de blog. En cuanto lo que dices que NO se descargue directo del Post (Entrada de Blog), si no es así porque la idea es que el usuario ingrese al Post lo lea y descargue los archivos directamente solo haciendo Click sobre los enlaces sin que sea redireccionado o salga del Post. En conclusión que apenas haga Click salte la ventana de descarga. La cosa es que el script funciona pero solo fuera de WP.